# my code is like this but whie printing color i get response like this(\n Blue \n) help me out

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

```
Alamofire.request("http://ca.crazendemand.com/Api/getProductDetail?proid=5&userid=79&device_type=A", method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON
            {(response) in



            if let result = response.result.value as? NSDictionary
            {

                let Str = result.value(forKey: "variant")as! NSArray
                let StrColor = Str.value(forKey: "Color")
                self.LblColor.text = String(describing: StrColor)


            }

        }
```

json looks like this

```
{
    "wishlist": [{
        "wishlist": 0
    }],
    "cart": [{
        "cart": 0
    }],
    "product": [{
        "promo_id": 0,
        "avals": 0,
        "dis": null,
        "mp_product_id": 5,
        "mp_category_id": 92,
        "product_name": "Cnd Blue Coloured Georgette Fabric Printed Semi-Stitched Suit For Girls ",
        "product_description": "",
        "sku_number": "D_828_1",
        "qty": 25,
        "likes_count": 0,
        "list_price": 1599,
        "selling_price": 1599,
        "discount": 0
    }],
    "image": [{
        "image_name": "828.jpg"
    }],
    "variant": [{
        "Color": "BLUE",
        "Size": "FREE SIZE",
        "Occasion": "Party"
    }],
    "related": []
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 let StrColor = (Str.object(at: 0) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "Color") as! String
 self.LblColor.text = String(describing: StrColor)
```

**OR**

```
let Str = result.value(forKey: "variant")as! [Any]
let objColor = Str[0] as! [String : Any]
let StrColor = objColor["Color"]  as! String
let string = String(describing: StrColor)
```